# comparing 2 columns in pandas and outputting row

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

I have the following dataframe in pandas and want to write a if statement to compare `name` with `new-name` and print `identifier` , `person-name`, `new-identifier` , `new-person`

| identifier | person-name | type | name | new-identifier | new-person | new-type | new-name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (hockey, player) | sidney crosby | athlete | sidney | (pittsburg, player) | crosby-sidney | player | SC |
| (hockey, player) | sidney crosby | athlete | sidney | (pittsburg, player) | crosby-sidney | player | MS |
| (hockey, player) | wayne gretzky | athlete | wayne | (oilers, player) | gretzky-wayne | player | WG |
| (hockey, player) | wayne gretzky | athlete | wayne | (oilers, player) | gretzky-wayne | player | TP |

I need help writing the if statement in pandas; if sidney = SC, output output would be:

| identifier | person-name | new-identifier | new-person |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (hockey, player) | sidney crosby | (pittsburg, player) | crosby-sidney |

```
 df[person-name].equals(df[new-person])
```

wouldn't work since I'm comparing contents in the column rather than the entire column. How can I compare the contents of those 2 columns and print the 4 columns

Comment: the logic is unclear, do you want to specifically match sidney crosby and SC?

Comment: yes, likewise with wayne gretzky and WG. I need help writing the if statement for 1 of them

Comment: how does it generalize? Do you want to match the initial or everything manually?

Comment: everything manually, just wanted to know how to compare the contents of the columns. The answer works well for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use

```py
out = df[df['name'].eq('sidney') & df['new-name'].eq('SC')]
```

To output specific column, you can use

```py
out = df[df['name'].eq('sidney') & df['new-name'].eq('SC')].filter(regex='identifier|person')
```